# Symfony - Cache access problem for a single random folder

Tags: symfony, caching, debian, symfony-3.4

I have a problem with symfony caching. Randomly, a folder is created with the wrong access rights (see photo). All other cache files are ok.

[Access list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wyx6.png)

If I empty the cache, everything works again but a few days later, same problem but on another folder.

I do not understand why it creates a file with bad access (root access) only for one folder and not the others (user apache access).

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: Did you check crontab for root user? `00:30` time looks like scheduled

Comment: It can be a cache folder created by a cli command you executed in root.